# Spring MongoRepository : Convert to binary before inserting into MongoDB

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

This might be a simple question, but I am not an expert with Spring. 
I have a class Message that represents documents in a collection called "messages" in mongoDB.

```
@Document(collection = "archive")

public class Message{
    @Id
    private String messageId;

    private String from;
    private String to;
    // more stuff

}
```

The interface `MessagesRepository` extends `MongoRepository<Message,String>`:

```
public interface MessagesRepository extends MongoRepository<Message, String>{

}
```

I have `MongoRepository.findOne(ID)` method calls where ID is a string, across different modules in my code.

It all works fine. The ID, called `messageId` is a `String`. But I want to insert it into Mongo in `binary encoded` format. My first rough guess was to do

```
@Id
private byte[] messageId;
```

in the Message class

But it neither felt right to me, nor worked because I found out I was getting different `byte[]` for different String objects even with the same values.

I've seen MongoMappingConverter, but not sure if it works. Can someone throw some light?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no way to do that automatically as of now. However, to achieve this I've only changed the messageId from String to byte[].

That seems to have worked.

And correction : the `find()` method of Spring-Data doesn't work with a `byte[]` but Mongo's java driver works so I'm going to adjust the Spring-Data methods.